# AttributeError when using custom form field

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and am trying to create a custom captcha field for a Django form. I wasn't able to find a good teaching tool for this, so I just poked around the code of the built-in fields and tried to learn from them. There's two major problems with my field. First of all, the widget for it is not displaying on the screen. Second of all, when I submit the form, Django raises an AttributeError saying: `"'CaptchaField' object has no attribute 'disabled'"`. I'm not sure why this is.

```
class CaptchaField(IntegerField):
validators = [validators.ProhibitNullCharactersValidator]
widget = CaptchaInput
error_msgs = { 'incorrect': _('Captcha incorrect- try again'), }

def __init__(self):
    captcha_array = [

    ('What is the product of fifteen and four?', 60),
    ('What is four plus four?', 8),

    ]
    captcha =captcha_array.pop(random.randrange(len(captcha_array)))
    self.captcha = captcha



def validate(self, value):
    for (a,b) in captcha:
        if value == b:
            return True
        else:
            raise ValidationError(self.error_msgs['incorrect'], code = 'incorrect')
```

My widget:

```
  class CaptchaInput(Widget):
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/captcha.html'


    def __init__(self, captcha, attrs = None):
        captcha = self.captcha
        attrs = self.attrs


    def get_context(self, captcha, attrs = None):
        return {'widget': {'captcha': captcha}}

    def render(self, captcha, attrs=None):
        context = self.get_context(captcha, attrs)
        template = loader.get_template(self.template_name).render(context)
        return mark_safe(template)
```

The html:

`<div class="card"><b>{{ a }}</b></div>
    {% include django/forms/widgets/input.html %}`

Full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/new/

Django Version: 2.1.7
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'posts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/bin/thewire/posts/views.py" in NewPost
  39.       if form.is_valid():

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  381.         self._clean_fields()

File "/home/self/python-virtualenv/thewire/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_fields
  390.             if field.disabled:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /new/
Exception Value: 'CaptchaField' object has no attribute 'disabled'
```

Form:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,  *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for key in ['postTitle', 'postContent', 'category']:
            self.fields[key].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})         
        self.fields['postContent'].widget.attrs.update(width='100px', height='50')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('postTitle', 'postContent', 'category')

    captcha = forms.CaptchaField()
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is happening.  Edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: That was remiss of me not to include, you're right.

Comment: Show us the `NewPost` view, and the form it's using.

Comment: I don't think the view is the issue, but I did post the form.

Comment: Please show us NewPost view.